# How foreach array in array in php?

Tags: php

I have an arrays in array:

```
$tree = array(array($value => 7, $left => 2, $right => 3, $leftValue = 0), 
              array($value => 5, $left => 4, $right => "", $leftValue = 0),
              array($value => 25, $left => 5, $right => 6, $leftValue = 0),
              array($value => 3, $left => "", $right => "", $leftValue = 0),
              array($value => 12, $left => "", $right => "", $leftValue = 0),
              array($value => 17, $left => "", $right => "", $leftValue = 0));
```

how make foreach main array to get values of inner array?

Comment: `foreach($tree as $entry) { echo $entry[$value], PHP_EOL; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints Array because $myarray is array, modify your script like this:

```
foreach ($tree as $myarray) {
   echo $myarray[$value];
   echo $myarray[$left];
   echo $myarray[$leftValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach ($tree as $outer) {
  foreach ($outer as $inner) {
    // here you are
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will sure work for you

```
$tmp_arr = array();
foreach ($tree as $parent_arr) {
  foreach($parent_arr as $key => $values) {
    $tmp_arr [$key] = $values;
  }
}
$tree = $tmp_arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($tree as $subtree) { 
    echo $subtree[$value]; 
}
```